# how can I toggle animation in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make like this. when I click about, willshow left : 0, html close.
And when I click again, willshow left : -100%, html about.
How can I realize this?

```
var about = $('ul.about > li > span.activebtn');
var willshow = $('div.willshow');

about.on('click', function(){

        willshow.animate({
            'left': '0'
        }, 500);
        about.html('close');

        if($(this).html() == 'close'){
            about.click(function(){
                willshow.animate({
                    'left': '-100%'
                }, 500);
                about.html('about');
            });
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the current state of the element to set the next value when being toggled. Try this:

```
var $about = $('ul.about > li > span.activebtn');
var $willshow = $('div.willshow');

$about.on('click', function() {
    $willshow.animate({ 
        left: $willshow.css('left') == '0px' ? '-100%' : 0
    }, 500);
    $about.text(function(i, t) {
        return t == 'close' ? 'about' : 'close';
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/5c0997z8/)

Comment: text is `toggle`ing. but css left isn't toggled.

Comment: You're right, answer updated with a working example too

Comment: you r the best. thank you so much XD !!!! I didn't know this way. I learn tanks to you